# Как передать переменную из одного файла в другой?

Tags: php

Имеется файл 1.php, в котором хранится значение переменной $id, есть второй файл 2.php, в котором написан SQL-запрос, в котором сравнивается значение переменной $id со значением id из БД. Пространства имен пробовал использовать - они некорректно работают в этом проекте. Помогите, пожалуйста. И не надо говорить, что я должен пойти гуглить\читать книгу. Уже гуглил - безуспешно. Да, я многих вещей не знаю, но не нужно из-за этого кидаться палками. Спасибо.

Часть кода из файла 1.php:

```
...
echo '<td class="bug-id">', $t_formatted_bug_id, '</td>';
...
```

Часть кода из файла 2.php:

```
...
$mysql = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);
$query = "UPDATE `mantis_bug_table` SET `target_version` = '123' WHERE `id` = '$t_formatted_bug_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysql, $query)  or die("ERROR " . mysqli_error($mysql));
...
```

Comment: Для того чтобы передать переменную из одного файла в другой нужно использовать `Get` или `Post` запрос

Comment: Ну можете проинклюдить файл и юзать его не передавая никаких данных так сказать по ветру. Объектно ориентированный стиль должен вас спасти от этих палок. 

А в вашем случае, include, curl.

Answer (score 0):

в ссылку через знак вопроса добавь название переменной и чему она равняется. Например, `/1.php?id=1`. В php-коде это будет выглядеть так:

```
<a href = " . $namePage . "?text=" . $row["id"] . ">" . нужный текст . "</a>
```